# multiple upload's title not saved to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am sorry but these solutions din't solved my purpose. So m giving more detail of my code,

```
var a=0;
    function _add_more() {
        var txt = "<br><input type=\"file\" name=\"item_file[]\"><br><input type=\"text\" name=\"text[]\">";
        document.getElementById("dvFile").innerHTML += txt;
        alert(a);
        a=a+1;

    }
```

here i have used a to increement title.

```
function upload(){  
    if(count($_FILES["item_file"]['name'])>0) { //check if any file uploaded
        $GLOBALS['msg'] = ""; //initiate the global message
        for($j=0; $j < count($_FILES["item_file"]['name']); $j++) { //loop the uploaded file array
            $filen = $_FILES["item_file"]['name']["$j"]; //file name
            $path = 'uploads/'.$filen; //generate the destination path
            $text=$_POST['text']['name']["$j"] + "<br>";
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["item_file"]['tmp_name']["$j"],$path)) { 

            $insert=mysql_query("insert into image_upload set title='".$text."', image='".$filen."'") or die(mysql_error());

            //upload the file
                $GLOBALS['msg'] .= "File# ".($j+1)." ($filen) uploaded successfully<br>"; //Success message
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $GLOBALS['msg'] = "No files found to upload"; //Failed message  
    }

    uploadForm(); //display the main form
}
```

this is what i have done. Please help me to get title for each uploaded file. as i am able to save different images in database but title appears to be same for all in database.

Comment: This code is a mess. You don't check if an upload succeeded at all, you have SQL injection vulnerabilities. Multiple invocations of the script will overwrite previous uploads. But I'll give you this much: at least you're checking if the mysql query failed.

Comment: my upload script is working fine and also it is saved to database, the only problem is that i am unable to save multiple titles, it shows me multiple textboxes for title but in database it is not saved

Comment: You should use `$_POST['text'][$j]` instead. but that doesn't change the fact that this script is a buggy pile of junk. It may work once, but as soon as you upload a second file, the first file will be trashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$text=$_POST['text'][$j];
```